# Eclipse regex to match all Java lines without var assignment

Tags: eclipse, refactoring

I'm trying to refactor my codebase with var assignment statement.

Turn this:

```
int i = -1;
double x = 0.0;
```

Into this:

```
var i = -1;
var x = 0.0;
```

I'm looking for a way to match only those lines.
With the leading white spaces, without public, private, this., var, etc.

Tried `^\S*(?!var|this\.|private ).*=.*$`.

Comment: Was able to reduce the search space with `^    (?!var) .* = .*$`.

Comment: You misunderstand what lookarounds do. `^    (?!var) .* = .*$` = `^     .* = .*$`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew No need to do this error-prone with regular expressions, since there is a built-in clean-up function for that: see my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to do this error-prone with regular expressions, since there is a built-in clean-up function for that:

Go to ***Source > Clean Up...***, tab ***Java Feature***, section ***Java 10*** and check the checkbox ***Use local variable type inference***.